# Broken rear window defroster terminal

Tags: defroster

'05 Mercedes CLK500 (W209)
I have a broken rear window defroster post. Is there a product I can use to solder/weld/join the mostly broken tab coming from the windshield grid, into the female connector? E.g.: Liquid Weld
The female connector has the broken post lodged in it still.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot solder or weld to the window and please don't try as it will likely break the window.

There are products on the market to repair these, your best bet is to visit your local auto parts store where they usually have such things.  I am sure you can also find them on your favorite online retailer.

Carefully read the instructions first and if you believe it's above your skill level, you can also find auto shops that do this type of work.

Comment: Tha k ypu for your reply! I have a piece of the post still intact. Can two pieces of one post be soldered, liquid or heat, back together? As you know there is a product on the market called Liquid Solder.

Comment: You cannot solder to the window, it will likely break.  Use a product specifically intended for window defroster repair.